# Mass edit the value of an HTML form to match the name

Tags: html, forms

I have a pretty big form with over 4000 values defined by the `<option>` tag.

I would like to match all values with the visible name. Currently it looks like this:

```
<option value="1">Name 1</option>
<option value="2">Name 2</option>
...
```

I would like to receive to achieve the following:

```
<option value="Name 1">Name 1</option>
<option value="Name 2">Name 2</option>
...
```

Can someone help me out with a solution?

Comment: Can you use Javascript / jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a perfect opportunity for in-editor jQuery, which I've been wanting a long time but have never found. So here's the next-best thing: find and replace with regular expressions! :D

Find:

```
<option(.+?)value=".*?"(.*?)>(.*?)</option>
```

Replace:

```
<option$1value="$3"$2>$3</option>
```

Voilà!